# CSS Transition not working on initial page load ONLY in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, transition

All verisons of IE this transition won't work. If you use this codepen on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, the transition works on page load. We're simply removing a class that has a transform translate. It should transition to the original transform translate. Why won't this work for IE, period?

```
$('.js-cat-nav-fixed-expanded').removeClass('cat_nav_expanded_close');
```

http://codepen.io/Wolfmans55/pen/rOGZoQ

Comment: Transitions work on IE10+ did you check those versions?

Comment: Yes I checked IE10 and IE11, it has to do with just initial page load. If you added and removed the class afterwards it's fine. Something to do with a timeout issue. Like it doesn't register the element before the transition fires.

Comment: If I give it a setTimeout(function() {
    $('.js-cat-nav-fixed-expanded').removeClass('cat_nav_expanded_close'); 
}, 0); it works.

Comment: Have you tried with [JQuerys .ready() event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1y65m46/).